# Why the radio button not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

```
question{
question_id,
option1,
option2,
option3,
option4,
answer
}

exam_paper{
exam_paper_id,
exam_paper_name
}

exam_question_list{
id,
exam_paper_id,
question_id
}

applicant_do_exam{
applicant_do_exam_id,
exam_paper_id,
question_id,
app_answer
}

I want to display the questions in exam_paper_id=1

$query="SELECT * FROM exam_question_list e LEFT JOIN question q ON e.question_id=q.question_id where exam_paper_id='$exid'";
$result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);

<form action="exampaper_result.php?id=<?php echo $exid; ?>&stime=<?php echo $stime?>" method="post">

<table>
<!--question_1-->
<?php 

        $i=1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

?>
  <tr>


     <tr  id="exquestion" data-label="QuestionID"><td><input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="<?php echo $row['question_id']; ?>" /></td></tr>
     <tr  id="exquestion" data-label="Question"><td><span><?php echo $i++; ?>)&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><?php echo $row['question']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input id="exoption" type="radio"  name="app_answer" value="1"/><?php echo $row['option1']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input id="exoption" type="radio"  name="app_answer" value="2"/><?php echo $row['option2']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input id="exoption" type="radio"  name="app_answer" value="3"/><?php echo $row['option3']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input id="exoption" type="radio"  name="app_answer" value="4"/><?php echo $row['option4']; ?></td></tr>  

 </tr>


<?php
    } 
    ?>

  </table>

  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>

  </form>
```

In here I can get the questions and their options correctly.
BUT I cannot select the radio button(answer) in each question.
The whole page given to select only one radio button for all question.

What is my error?

Comment: your radio buttons all have the same id.   That should not be.  They should all have the same name but every control should have a unique id.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: When I select the question 1 radio button(answer) , after I click the question 2 radio button(answer) then the question 1 radio button is deselected and question 2 radio button selected

Comment: I can select only one radio button in the whole page

Comment: For valid HTML all HTML elements should have a unique ID. `<tr id="abc1">` etc. Additionally you would need to break up the names for each section to allow for them to be selectable within their context. `name="app_answer[<?php echo $i; ?>]"` which will provide you with `$_POST['app_answer'] = array()`

Comment: I use $i for numbering questions, then is it possible to use in radio btton name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to break up the names for each section to allow for them to be selectable within their context. For example `name="app_answer[<?php echo $i; ?>]"` which will provide you with `$_POST['app_answer'] = array()`.

Like so:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $g = $row['question_id'];
?>
      <tr id="exquestion" data-label="Question"><td><span><?php echo $i++; ?>)&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><?php echo $row['question']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input id="exoption" type="radio"  name="app_answer[<?php echo $g; ?>]" value="1"/><?php echo $row['option1']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input id="exoption" type="radio"  name="app_answer[<?php echo $g; ?>]" value="2"/><?php echo $row['option2']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input id="exoption" type="radio"  name="app_answer[<?php echo $g; ?>]" value="3"/><?php echo $row['option3']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr data-label="Question"><td><input id="exoption" type="radio"  name="app_answer[<?php echo $g; ?>]" value="4"/><?php echo $row['option4']; ?></td></tr>  
<?php } /*end while*/ ?>
```

---

Result on submit

```
<?php
$answers = (array) $_POST['app_answer'];
//type-casted to ensure empty value is still a blank array
foreach ($answers as $question_id => $answer) {
   echo 'Answer to Question - ' . $question_id . ': ' . $answer . '<br/>';
}
exit;
```

You would need to be able to parse the key `$g`/`question_id` to your desired format.